# Setting custom TestExecutionListener for all test classes, so I can log the stack trace of every exception/assertion thrown

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, spring-test

Hey,
I'm using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. By default, the TestContextManager.afterTestMethod() logs every exception or assertion thrown very briefly (just the message), like so:

`testMethod = testDataDriven@DataDrivenAbstractTest, testException = [null]]`

I would like to write a custom TestExecutionListener that logs all exceptions thrown by **any test** in my project. I don't want to have to remember to annotate each of my test classes with  @TestExecutionListeners.

Can I somehow do it globally? am I on the right track?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it globally, but you can write a base class that uses the `TestExecutionListener` and let all other test classes extend it.

Or you can extend `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to do your stuff and run your tests with `@Runwith(YourCustomSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

Comment: Not true anymore, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-automatic-discovery

Comment: @theHacker when things change over time, the proper thing to do is add a new answer that should then get accepted by OP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-automatic-discovery

`SpringFactoriesLoader` will detect a `META-INF/spring.factories` file. In that file you put your listener:

```
org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener=com.example.YourCoolTestExecutionListener
```